# Firefox not ignoring fixed position elements when outside container width

Tags: css, firefox

I wasn't sure of the best way to explain this, but if you look at the example snippet in Chrome or Safari, the orange div does not cause the document to scroll horizontally when the window is narrower than the blue container. This is the desired behavior.

However, in Firefox, if you make the window narrow it counts the orange box as content that needs to be able to be scrolled to, causing the document to scroll to the right in an odd way that shifts the body content to the left and is ugly. What's also strange is that you'll notice the green box on the left DOESN'T cause it to have scrollable space to the left...is this a bug, or why is this happening?

Anyone else encountered this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1);
  color: #ffffff;
}

.banner:before, .banner:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: -100px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.banner:after {
  left: 100%;
  background-color: orange; 
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="banner">Banner</div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, but my work-around was to just add `overflow-x: hidden;` to the `body`. It doesn't explain it, but it makes it behave correctly.

Comment: You can do that, it's effectively the same as my answer, but I try not to hide overflow on `body` by default. I'd rather see overflow when it happens and fix what's causing it if I don't want it than to prohibit overflow entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap that in an element that will scale with the viewport and set `overflow: hidden` on that element. You can also remove the `transform: scale()` from `.banner` and use `position: absolute` on the pseudo elements, unless `scale(1)` is needed for some reason.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.banner {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.banner:before, .banner:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.banner:after {
  left: 100%;
  background-color: orange; 
}

.content {
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="banner">Banner</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
  </div>
</header>
```